# Is it possible to create a class of "Class Objects" in java?

Tags: java, class, object

Is it possible to create a class that contains objects of the type `Class`?
I know that the class `java.lang.class` is final and cannot have sub classes.

Comment: Are you asking if a class can containg fields like `Class someClass`

Comment: What prevents you from creating your own class with a java.lang.Class as a field? java.lang.Class is a class like any other one and can be used as any other class.

Comment: The fact that class `java.lang.Class` is `final` doesn't prevent you from creating fields of type `Class` in your own class (in other words: this doesn't have any implications for your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Class` is an `Object` just like `String` or `Integer`. As such, you could keep a collection of `Class` objects in a `List`, for example.

```java
public class ClassTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Collection<Class> classes = new ArrayList<>(3);
    classes.add(String.class);
    classes.add(Integer.class);
    classes.add(ClassTest.class);

    for (Class storedClass : classes) {
      System.out.println(storedClass.getSimpleName());
    }
  }

}
```

This returns

```
String
Integer
ClassTest
```

If you want to keep these `Class` references within your own `class`, you can save the values within the instance (or static) fields and return these as appropriate to your needs, e.g.

```java
public void ClassStore {
  private Class myFavouriteClass; // Set in constructor or setter method
  private List<Class> otherClasses; // Set in constructor or setter method

  ...

  public Class getMyFavouriteClass() {
    return myFavouriteClass;
  }

  public List<Class> getOtherClasses() {
    return otherClasses;
  }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. I would add a mention that `Class` objects are routinely passed as arguments. Example: `myResultSet.getObject( 1 , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;` ([Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject(int,java.lang.Class)))

Comment: In this case, one should write `Class<?>`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it.